# Google maps on site connected to map in iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-api, maps

I have a site with google map. I want to create an iOS app that can add markers on map and this markers should be on my site. How to do it, it will help my sister alot in her life. Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the coordinates from database, present them using iOS google maps SDK, add new markers, upload them back to database.